# rails 3 modular application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to create a rails 3 project which will serve as a skeleton for all my future apps. This skeleton will provide everything I need to get started faster on new projects (roles, members, permissions, authentication).

Would be nice if I could wrap all of this functionality as a separate application in my project, let's say a "skeleton" folder with all of it's controllers models and stuff. If I need to build a blog I simply create a "blog" folder in the same directory as my skeleton app with it's controllers, models and etc. Blog will still be able to communicate with skeleton and query its models like in any real modular application.

Is this possible? Couldn't find any material so far,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [application templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#application-templates) and [Rails engines](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html).